# Weak solution to SDEs by Girsanov transform.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I meet a problem with the following exercise. Consider the following SDE:
$$
d X_t=b(X_t,Y_t)d t+d L_t
$$
and
$$
d Y_t=d W_t,
$$
where $L_t$ is a $\alpha$-stable process and $W_t$ is a Brownian motion.

How can I use the Girsanov to construct a weak solution to such SDE? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Where does this "exercise" come from?

Answer (score 0):

The true question is not "How can I ..?" but rather "Can I..?".

To apply any kind of Girsanov change of measure, you certainly need some exponential integrability. However, $\alpha$-stable processes do not even have finite variance.

And, unlike in the Gaussian framework, for $\alpha$-stable processes, the equivalence of measures is extremely rarely the case, even for deterministic shifts. In fact, since $L$ is purely discontinuous, the measures induced by $L_t$ and $L_t + \int_0^t \theta_s ds$ are never equivalent unless $\theta \equiv 0$.

So, unfortunately, the answer is

> No, you can't.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It is my mistake that I didn't point out the conditions on the drift $b$. The condition is that $b\in L^p(R^d_x;L^q(R^d_y))$ with $d/\alpha p+d/2q<1$. Thus, if we use the density of the process combining with the Khasminskii's estimate, we will find that the exponential expectation do exists.

Comment: @WenguangZhao, please add the assumption and your thoughts on using the Khasminskii estimate to the OP. Unrelated: "does exist".

Comment: Btw, I was not able to identify the "Khasminskii estimate" you speak about. Did you mean the *Krylov* estimate? Also you didn't answer about the source of the problem.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention. Consider the process $(L_t,W_t)$ (with $b=0$). By independent, the density is given by $p_\alpha(t,x)p_2(t,y)$, where $p_\alpha$ and $p_2$ denote the density of $L_t$ and $W_t$, respectively. As you mentioned, the following Krylov estimate holds: $$E\int_0^tf(L_s,W_s)d s\leq C\|f\|_{L^p_q}$$ with $d/\alpha p+d/2p<1$. Thus, by Khasminskii's Lemma, $$E\exp{\int_0^tf(L_s,W_s)d s}<\infty$$.

Comment: Ok, I know this as the Portenko lemma. Though it requires that $E\int ... \le \alpha<1$. It's rather meaningless to write this in the comments - please update the original post.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The condition $\alpha<1$ here is not a problem for me. Of course, there are many ways to construct a weak solution to to such SDE. But I just don't known how to use the Girsanov transform in this case. A question posed in a discussion class. Many thanks.

Comment: Anyway, I don't see what the exponential integrability of the drift has to do with integrability of the Girsanov exponent (which involves some integral w.r.t. $L_t$). I've slightly updated the third paragraph of the answer. It essentially says that no Girsanov-transformation tricks are possible here.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much for your patient answers. All the best.